# PyCharm and NLTK: code completion (autocomplete) doesn't work

Tags: python, nltk, pycharm, code-completion

I use PyCharm.
I have installed PySide and NLTK via PIP. Both PySide and NLTK work well.

The code completion in PyCharm works for PySide well. The code completion works for NLTK objects, but it offered no NLTK methods. It shows only private methods like "update", "dir", "doc", "str" with underscores.

In the Python 3.4.0 Shell IDLE works code completion for NLTK well. 
In the PyDev (Eclipse) works code completion for NLTK well.

Windows 7 64 Bit, PyCharm 3.0.1 Pro and now 3.4.1 Pro, Python 3.4.0, NLTK 3.0.0

Any ideas?

[image: no code completion for NLTK]
[image: package NLTK is installed]
[image: paths]
[image: code completion works in Python 3.4.0 Shell IDLE well]
[image: code completion works in PyDev]

Answer (score 0):

Code completion will not always work in the editor, meaning that you won't get all the options most of the time, but you will get them in the interpreter.

In the interpreter, pycharm has access to everything thats happening in real time, hence it can use python's reflection tools to give you the information you want on your objects. It cannot do so in the editor.

The only way to get better code completion for an existing library is to make a skeleton/stub for it. See [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons).

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful hint. Here's what I do not understand however: Why works the code completion for NLTK methods in the Python Shell 3.4.0 IDLE?

Comment: Same principle as the interpreter in PyCharm. Also, if this answered your question, feel free to upvote and accept.

Comment: Same principle as the interpreter in PyCharm? I don't understand you. Code completion **works** in the Python Shell 3.4 IDLE - but it **does not work** in PyCharm. What are you mean with "same principle"? For me this is not the same... If it works in Python Shell 3.4 IDLE, then we can also make it work in PyCharm.

Comment: The question is, how do we do that without skeleton/stub?

Comment: Well code completion will work in PyCharm's console too not in the editor itself. And you can't without a stub.

Comment: Do you think it will not work only in PyCharm? PyDev is also an editor: In PyDev works code completion for NLTK methods, see the pictures above.

Comment: @Igor I think you're using an old version of pycharm. Try 3.4, I just got completion to work.

Comment: I use the latest version of PyCharm 3.4.1 Pro. I have reinstalled PyCharm, Python and NLTK - no effect. Which system do you have? Linux? Works for you code completion with NLTK methods (or only private methods, see above)?

Comment: I'm on a mac. I don't understand why you're facing this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because `wn` hasn't been resolved into a concrete type yet. If you read the documentation, `wn` is of type `LazyCorpusLoader` at first. Upon usage, the concrete class `WordNetCorpusReader` is assigned to `wn`, and this is when your code completion will work. I didn't read the documentation fully, but it seems like this was done to cut computation overhead for loading Corpora.

### Before the class has been loaded

Code completion does not work.

[image: Before class loaded]

### After the class has been loaded

Code completion works as expected.

[image: After class loaded]

Unfortunately this does not fix your problem, but at least I hope this provides some answer to others who are encountering the same issue.